# Even though I installed the necessary packages in Visual Studio, there is no asp.net core web app option

Tags: asp.net, .net, model-view-controller

Even though I installed the necessary packages in Visual Studio, there is no asp.net core web app option. How can I fix this problem?

Changing the language fixes it, but the English language option disappears.

Comment: Can you please provide some more details. By *I installed the necessary packages* you mean that you have installed some workloads using the Visual Studio Installer? Which workloads did you install? Which button disappears? Can you create a project using the `dotnet` CLI? E.g. for a Web API project using `dotnet new webapi -o MyApi`?

Comment: what kind of project? You for example don't have a .net core choice for WebForms, but you do for MVC applications.

Comment: I installed all .net related packages in the visual studio installer section.